# Bitbucket is saying to merge, but my branch is up to date

Tags: git, bitbucket, egit

I think the title says it all.  I have a branch in bitbucket but when I try to merge with master it says there are conflicts and gives me instructions to merge.  Basically:

1. go to local master
2. pull master from origin
3. got to local branch
4. merge local branch from local master
5. when i do this, it says up to date and therefore there is nothing new to push to my branch.

Im kind of stuck at this point.  any ideas on how to resolve?

Comment: _merge local branch from local master_ It sounds like you're trying to do this backwards.  The usual way to merge is to be in the older branch (master in your case), and then run a merge command on the newer branch.  If you do it the other way around, then yeah, it will say there aren't any changes.

Comment: @JohnGordon  using eGit...you usually get onto your working branch and select merge or rebase.  it asks you for the source to merge/rebase from and i select local master (also tried origin master)

here is the message - Select a branch or tag to merge into the 'MYBRANCH' branch

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with bitbucket or eGit, so maybe their workflows are different than what I'm used to.

Comment: @JohnGordon Those instructions are not for making the final merge into master, they are for updating the working branch to contain other people's work from master. The point being to resolve any conflicts and commit the result to the unprotected working branch, because changes can only be made to master via a reviewed Pull Request / Merge Request. The slightly more advanced version is to rebase the local branch onto master at step 4, which should end up with the same code but a slightly tidier history.